# How to refer program created Controls in a module for a ms-access project

Tags: ms-access

I have an access project wherein I have created some labels at runtime based on some database values. Now it works when I try to refer them within the form, as:

```
Controls("lbl" & !DB_Val ).BackColor = vbBlue
```

But when I try to move this code to a module, it fails. I even tried changing it to:

```
Forms!FormName!Controls("lbl" & !DB_Val).BackColor = vbBlue
```

Any pointers to the right syntax to do this within a module? TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try-

```
Forms![FormName].Controls("lbl" & !DB_Val).BackColor = vbBlue
```

Comment: I am surprised I didn't try that by myself.. you are a lifesaver :)) ... thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Read here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.controls

https://www.fmsinc.com/tpapers/primer/index.html

It will help you. To references to Forms and Controls in MS Access VBA.